# Trigger click once when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in my page like so:

```
     <form id="shipping" action="some-action-url" method="post">
        <ul>
         <li>
          <input id="ship238280" name="method" value="238280|479435" type="radio" checked="checked">
          <label for="ship238280">Transport (€0,00)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
          <input id="ship292259" name="method" value="292259|580109" type="radio">
          <label for="ship292259">Pick up (€0,00)</label>
         </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
```

I'm using a SaaS platform so I have limited access to scripts and need to make use of what's actually available. So I'm looking for more of a workaround....

In above form I have checked the first option. To actually set the first shipping option I have to submit the form. Then in the system this option is set.

So I have a function that submits the form:

```
function sendform(){
  var loader = $('.cart-loader');
  var form = $('#shipping');

  $(loader).show()
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data: $(form).serialize(),
      success: function(data) { 
       $(loader).hide()
       //$(this).unbind()
      } 
    });
}
```

And a click event for when I click one of the options:

```
 $('#shipping input').on('click', function(){
   sendform()
 });
```

What I want now is to submit the form on page load. So I have created something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#shipping input').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).trigger('click') // or sendform()
     }
   });
});
```

What happens now is that the form keeps submitting because everytime the page reloads (after submit) it wants to submit again!

How can I work around this knowing that it needs to submit first to set the option?

I tried things like `$(document).one('ready', function(){` or something like `$(this).unbind()` in ajax success function.

I'm a bit lost :) So any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why no use Ajax to change the content of the page without reloading it?

Comment: Also where does this submit to and where is the form data stored? This process flow sounds strange. Explain how shipping option requires a submit first

Comment: @MickaelLeger: Well to set the option it needs to submit the form to an url. Let's say 'setshipment'. When that is doen the system sets the correct option. How things are handled there I don't have access to. I can set an option with ajax but then it's not loaded in the system so the system knows which option is set. It really have to be submitted to that form url

Comment: Well, maybe you can try to use some cookie to know if the form has been sent before so you don't do it again every time?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/noidee/uvm6jw3b/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if( localStorage.getItem('submited') !== '1' ){
    $('#myform').submit();
    localStorage.setItem('submited', '1');
  }
});
```